# Recursivo a iterativo con bottom-up

Tags: java

Este es mi código de una función recursiva escrita en forma no final , me gustaría pasarla a iterativa con un while , pero la verdad no consigo hacerla , consejos para hacerla con bottom-up? El método **abc** es una raíz cuadradra(x) , y el el numero de iteraciones realizadas(n) , cuanto mas mayor la iteración mejor es el resultado.

```
public static Double abc(int x,int n){
    Double d = .0;
    if(n==0){ //caso base
        d = 1.0;
    }else{
        d = (abc(x,n-1)+(x/abc(x,n-1)))/2;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Esto es lo que he probado con el bucle while:

```
  public static Double abcIter(Integer x,Integer n){                 
    Double res = 1.0;
    Double r0=.0;
    Integer numeroAuxiliar = 0;

        while(numeroAuxiliar<=n){

            res = (res+(x/res))/2;
            r0 = res;
            res = (r0+(x/r0))/2;
            numeroAuxiliar++;
        }


    return res;
}
```

Cuando pruebo alguna raíz e iteración con el while no me da el valor exacto. En cambio , el primer método si que me resulta bien.
¿Consejos sobre el metodo while, y bottom-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toda función recursiva con [recursión de cola](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)#Funciones_de_recursi.C3.B3n_de_cola) puede ser convertida en una función iterativa.
Una función con recursión de cola es aquella que siempre acaba en `return metodoRecursivo(parametros)` o en `return expresion_sin_llamada_recursiva`.

Tu función no es recursiva de cola pero se puede convertir a recursiva de cola introduciendo un parámetro acumulador (este es el paso más difícil) :

```
public static Double abc(int x,int n){
  return abcRecurs(x, n, 1.0);
}  

public static double abcRecurs( int x, int n, double acc ) {
    if(n==0){ 
        return acc;
    }else{
        return abcRecurs( x, n-1,  (acc+x/acc)/2 );
    }
}
```

Una vez tenemos la función en forma recursiva de cola los pasos son siempre los mismos y se hacen de forma mecánica.
Primero poner un bucle `while (true)` alrededor de la función :

```
public static double abcRecurs(int x, int n, double acc) {
  while (true) {
    if (n == 0) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      return abcRecurs(x, n - 1, (acc + x / acc) / 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Segundo, cambiar todas las llamadas recursivas `abcRecurs( /*parm a*/ a1, /* parm b*/ b1, etc )` por : `a=a1; b=b1; etc; continue;`

```
public static double abcRecurs(int x, int n, double acc) {
  while (true) {
    if (n == 0) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      x = x;
      n = n - 1;
      acc = (acc + x / acc) / 2;
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Y ya tienes tu función iterativa. Para acabar puedes limpiarla un poco. Por ejemplo `x=x;` no sirve para nada.

```
public static double abcRecurs(int x, int n, double acc) {
  while ( n>0 ) {
    --n;
    acc = (acc + x / acc) / 2;
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Y tras esto puedes combinar abc y abcRecurs en una sola :

```
public static Double abc(int x, int n) {
  double acc = 1.0;
  while (n > 0) {
    --n;
    acc = (acc + x / acc) / 2;
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto.

```
public static Double abcIter(Integer x, Integer n) {
    Double res = 1.0;
    Integer numeroAuxiliar = n;

    while (numeroAuxiliar !=0) {
        res = (res + (x / res)) / 2;
        numeroAuxiliar--;
    }

    return res;
}
```